# Getting error while making use of hyperlinks from different cells

Tags: vba, web-scraping, hyperlink

I've written a script in vba to make use of `hyperlinks` from `Range(A1")` to `Range("A2")` in order to scrape the `title` from each of the webpages. But, I get an error `Expected Function or Variable` pointing at `.FollowHyperlink` when I execute the following macro.

```
Sub getTitle()
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim cel As Range

    For Each cel In Sheets("summary").Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        If cel <> vbNullString Then
            With Http
                .Open "GET", ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink(cel), False
                .send
                Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            End With
            Debug.Print Html.queryselector("p.ueberschrift").innertext
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

> How can I use those hyperlinks to parse the title from webpages?

The following image shows how the hyperlinks look like in the cells:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a string, more specifically an absolute url, to pass after `GET` in the `Open` method of XMLHttpRequest. Instead, you are trying to use [Workbook.FollowHyperlink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.followhyperlink), which is an expression that returns a `Workbook` object. The result can be of the following:

> Displays a cached document, if it's already been downloaded.
>   Otherwise, this method resolves the hyperlink, downloads the target
>   document, and displays the document in the appropriate application.

What you are trying is not possible as is.

The syntax would be:

```
If cel <> vbNullString Then
            ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink cel.Value
```

You will likely then notice a new tab/browser window open to display the appropriate web document if valid.

The peculiarity of your message I believe is due to your use of parentheses around the parameter.

You can retrieve the underlying address of the hyperlink:

```
.Open "GET", cel.Hyperlinks(1).Address, False
```

Comment: What does this ***1*** within `Hyperlinks(1)` mean? Thanks QHarr for the solution.

Comment: A range or worksheet can have more than one hyperlink. Use Hyperlinks ( index ), where index is the hyperlink number, to return a single Hyperlink object.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlink